# Video is not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am using following code to show video on my website. It is working perfect in **Firefox** and **Google Chrome** but not working in **IE**.

```
<video class="video-js" width="278" height="165" controls preload>

    <source src="/uploads/video/encoding/mp4/<?php echo $video->getId() ?>.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="/uploads/video/encoding/ogg/<?php echo $video->getId() ?>.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

    <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="278" height="165" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">

      <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
      <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
      <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png", {"url": "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":false}]}' />

    </object>

</video>
```

I searched for that but not succeeded yet. Is there any programing solution of this without installing any third party plugin on IE.

Thanks

Comment: the code you wrote seems working correctly... have you installed flash plugin for IE?

Comment: I did not check this. How can I check this ?

Comment: Saying the version of IE is always important. What version are you testing with IE 6,7,8,9,10?

Comment: just copied the <object>...</object> snippet into jsfiddle. The video is correctly loaded. Since IE<9 doesn't recognize <video> and <source> elements it will try to render the object as a fallback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 is not supported by versions that came before IE9. Therefore, the video tag is not recognized. The [object tag was introduced in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT), but some earlier versions of IE either had bugs with it or did not support it at all.

In short, you need to create a fallback with the proprietary `<embed>...</embed>` tag instead of `<object>...</object>`.

**OR**

A better solution would be to use the [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) which creates the HTML5 elements through JavaScript for the previous versions of IE.

You would have to place the following in your head section:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can view some interesting explanations and other useful tools on [NetTuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-and-css3-without-guilt/).

Answer (score 5):

Older versions of ie before ie9 don't support html5.

Use embed as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Only IE 9+ supports the html5 video tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106

Comment: No need for a reference... Earlier versions of IE are known for the lack of compliance to standards. :P

Answer (score 1):

Out of the IE browsers only IE9 [supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) the video tag, make sure you use that version to test it, or you'll have to use fallbacks. All other recent browser support it, but check the link to see from which versions exactly.

Comment: To be clear, all current browsers support the video tag but only version 9 of IE.

Answer (score 0):

For IE browsers, you can make use of [video4all](https://code.google.com/p/video4all).